# Langevin equation with uniform noise

Tags: stochastic-analysis

Given the Langevin equation written in the form:

$$\ddot{x}(t)+\lambda \dot{x}(t)=\mu(t)$$

if $\mu(t)$ is noise with gaussian $pdf$, the solution is well known in therms of the spectrum of the $x(t)$
Now, my question is: if $\mu(t)$ is a random variable with uniform $pdf$, what is the spectrum of $x(t)$?

Thanks in advance for every suggestion